# How to get html range input type's max value through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, range

If I have set:

```
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100">
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="255">
```

How can I use jQuery/JavaScript to get the min and max value?

I want to do something like this later, I can get the max value and parse it to a variable `maxValue`.

```
if (maxValue == 100) {console.log("100");}
else if (maxValue == 255) {console.log("255");}
```

Comment: you will have 2 max and 2 min values. which one do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an array of maximum values, simply access the `max` property of the element:

```
var maxValues = $('input.slider').map(function(){
    return this.max;
}).get();

// ['255', '255']
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/D7TA3/).

Obviously, to find the `max` of a specific element, use a specific selector.

Answer (score 5):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var minValue= $('.slider[type="range"]').prop('min');
var maxValue = $('.slider[type="range"]').prop('max');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery instead..

```
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **only JavaScript** you can pass the values to a function:

in HTML:

```
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="showResult(this.min, this.max)">
<p id=max>Max value will appear here</p>
<p id=min>Min value will appear here</p>
```

in JavaScript:

```
function showResult(min, max) {
    // Use min and max variables as desired

    // Display min and max in HTML
    document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = max;
    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = min;
}
```

Try it out here https://jsfiddle.net/vdja45xo/